# Protractor internet explorer tests unstable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a angular web application that I want to make protractor tests for the page, And I must run the tests with Internet explorer browser.

However, the tests are not stable, sometimes they all work, sometimes few tests fail randomly.

I am having this issue from 1 month now and I still cannot find solution, here what I tried so far:

- Running IEwebdriver explicitly in 32bit or 64bit.
- Deleting cache and session after every test.
- Increased timeouts in conf.js to 200000.
- Adding protractor expected conditions(http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)
- Making sure using `.then` after every function that returns promise.

The reasons of tests failing  is slowness of internet explorer, and that it waits for element to be clickable(using protractor expectedconditions) but the element is never clickable, and when I look at the webdriver-manager I see that it trying to do the same lines over and over again.

I am sure that my tests are correct and working fine and I am sure that the browser is the problem.

Can you help? Thanks